# Match parenthesis containing specific character

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have a string:

```
var string = "116 b (407) (90 A / 122 M) (11.2004)"
```

In that string I want to match specific parenthesis `()` and its context (i.e. `(90 A / 122 M)`)  including specific character `/`.

I tried:

```
string.match(/\([/]\)/g)
```

But that returns `null`. What am I doing wrong?
Best Regards

Comment: Do you mean you want to match **only** if there is a slash inside the parens? By the way, I recommend using a site like regex101.com, which will "read aloud" your regexp to you. That should help you find the problem easily. You are looking for a set of parentheses with a single slash character between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `\([/]\)` pattern matches a `(`, followed with `/`, followed with `)`, a 3-char sequence.

You may use

```
/\([^()]*\/[^()]*\)/g
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bk2UIx/1)

**Details**:

- `\(` - opening `(` parenthesis
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` (a `\/` can be added at the end to improve performance a bit: `[^()\/]*`)
- `\/` - a `/` symbol
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - closing parenthesis

Comment: Wouldn't you want to adhere to a more concrete regular expression? e.g. `/\(\d+ [A-Z] \/ \d+ [A-Z]\)/g` => (VAL UNIT / VAL UNIT)

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl: The task was not to suggest a precise pattern for the string in question, but to *Match parenthesis containing specific character*. Yes, otherwise, I would suggest something like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `string.match(/\([^)]*\)/g)`

which may give what you want:

`["(407)", "(90 A / 122 M)", "(11.2004)"]`

Comment: He seems to want to match only parens with a slash inside.

Comment: @torazaburo I hardly thinks so .. ! Or maybe I got you wrong

Comment: @torazaburo Which is strange... I wish OP had more context in the question. Just matching parens with slashes is odd and will increase the time is takes to find matches.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/\([^(/]*\/[^)]*\)/g
```

#### [Online Pattern](https://regex101.com/r/Bk2UIx/2)

Comment: Thanks to you too:)